# How is the dispute of EEZ of nations resolved?

Tags: international-law, international, geopolitics

An exclusive economic area/zone covers an area which is around 200 kilometers from country's shoreline but how is the EEZ of a nation resolved when EEZ of two nations are overlapping?  For example, if China's & Japan's EEZ are overlapping then who will get preference?  Or can such disputes only be resolved by military might of one's nation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclusive economic zones (EEZ) are defined in the [UN Convention on the laws of the sea](https://www.un.org/Depts/los/convention_agreements/texts/unclos/unclos_e.pdf). Article 15 describes how overlapping zones are handled (emphasis mine):

> Where the coasts of two States are opposite or adj
>   acent to each other,
>   neither of the two States is entitled, failing agreement between them to the
>   contrary, to extend its territorial sea beyond **the median line every point of
>   which is equidistant from the nearest points on the baselines** from which the
>   breadth  of  the  territorial  seas  of  each  of  the  two  States  is  measured.    The
>   above provision does not apply, however, where it is necessary by reason of
>   historic title or other special circumstances to delimit the territorial seas of the
>   two States in a way which is at variance therewith.

Contrary agreements are not uncommon. For example [parts of the North Sea are divided up in an unusual way between the Netherlands, Germany and Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Sea#/media/File:North_sea_eez.PNG). But such agreements are usually voluntary and agreed upon by all parties.

However, in the case of the Chinese and Japanese claims, you have the problem that people don't agree on the baseline. There are, for example the <strike>Senkaku islands</strike> <strike>Diaoyu islands</strike> <strike>Diaoyutai islands</strike> <strike>Pinnacle islands</strike>  [a couple of uninhabited rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senkaku_Islands_dispute) which are disputed. The islands themselves are economically unimportant, but if those claims would be internationally recognized, it would result in an extension of the EEZ of the respective country.

And then there is the "necessary by reason of historic title or other special circumstances" clause in the UNCLOS Article 15. This rather rubbery paragraph leaves a lot of room for arguments based on history.

One peaceful way to resolve such disputes is through the [International Court of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Court_of_Justice). But the ICJ is only allowed to make binding judgments if all parties of a dispute explicitly consent to submit to the decision of the court. When one involved party doesn't want the ICJ to settle the matter, they won't.